# Azure DevOps project setup - 1 team - 1 board 3 projects is this possible?

Tags: azure-devops, task, project, epic

I am working with azure dev ops and I am trying to organize 3 different projects with the same team with one board. Is this possible in Azure DevOps?

Because if I use a planning board for each project (but the people are the same in each project) the weekly sprint planning is kinda confusing.

Like I said I dream of 1 planning board but to handle epics task etc from 3 different projects in it and assign a task from all project to one person.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Whitin a same organization it is recommended to work with a single Azure DevOps project, which minimizes the maintenance of administrative tasks and allows full flexibility to [cross-link objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/link-work-items-support-traceability?view=vsts) (see [when to add another project to my organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/about-projects?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav#when-to-add-another-project)).

For each application in your organization create a repository under the same single project.

And to manage and configure your team work have a look on [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/manage-teams?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav).

Comment: I would love to just have 2 backlogs in the same project. This should be possible since on the left side in the project navigation is the word "backlogs" plural.

Comment: Just add a second team to the project, and you will have a second backlog for this newly created team.

Comment: Ok - got it - but it didnt came out as expected. Is it possible to get all backlogs from Team1, Team2 and Team3 on the same planing board. 

So basically 3 teams - 3 backlogs - but 1 board. Or is the "board-to-team" relationship 1..1?
I would like to have 1 planning board for all teams - not a planing board for every team. I hope my idea gets across. Thank you for you answer.

Comment: Have a look to Delivery Plans (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/plans/review-team-plans?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav)